# Convergence of the sum of all odd digit numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

[I found the following exercise here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jmGr.png)

> Let $D_1$ denote the set of positive one-digit numbers $D_3$ and in general $D_n$ the seton $n$-digit number. Consider the following sum for any odd $n$:
> $$
> S_n =\sum_{k_1\in D_1} \frac{1}{k_1} + \sum_{k_1\in D_3} \frac{1}{k_3} + \sum_{k_1\in D_5} \frac{1}{k_5} +\cdots + \sum_{k_n\in D_n} \frac{1}{k_n}
> $$
> As $n$ tends to infinity, to what value $S_n$ tends to?

This problem came in my mocks. I tried writing the sum down and sandwiching it but I could not find appropriate "sandwiches" to this. Please help me with this. I nearly spent an hour on it and could not find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1.$ What is the size of $D_n$?

$2.$ What is a lower bound for $\sum_{k_n \in D_n} \frac{1}{k_n}$?

Comment: $9.10^{n-1}$ numbers in $D_{n}$

Comment: That's right. What about a naive lower bound for the sum now?

Comment: Well, Let us consider the the smallest value. $\frac{1}{999...9}(n 9's)$. If I create a sandwich with that then a lower bound would be $\frac{9.10^{n-1}}{10^n-1}$.

Comment: That's right. Maybe it would be even cleaner to just use $\frac{9 \cdot 10^{n-1}}{10^n}$. What do you observe now?

Comment: $\frac{9}{10}$ I have to construct a similiar upper bound. Thanks. Please let me try.

Comment: Well, you haven't constructed a lower bound for the whole series though! The number $\frac{9}{10}$ is a lower bound for each term in the series :)

Comment: Well, Then the sequence will never converge as it seems. Since the sum of $n$ terms would be greater than $\frac{9}{10}.n$

Comment: Perfect! Note that this is precisely the classical proof that the harmonic series diverges.